# Chrome Extensions; Javascript Inserting

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So, I am trying to insert a basic javascript script that works inside the console (and via [js.do](http://js.do)) into an extension. I have little experience with chrome extensions, although some experience with web pages and javascript.

My extension is displayed down below. My question is, how can I get the extension to insert this code into the active tab and work like [this](http://js.do/code/stopbrowserclose) does? (It stops the user from easily closing the browser on accident (or on purpose, however, leave can be clicked to close browser)

*manifest.json*

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Stop Chrome Closing",
    "description": "This extension stops chrome from closing by adding an `unsaved` progress notification when you attempt to close chrome",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["main.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

*main.js*

```
function main() {    
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        var confirmationMessage = 'It looks like you have been editing something. ' + 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.';

        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
        return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
    });
}
```

*popup.html*

```
This does nothing, nor will it ever
```

Comment: You need a content script. The background or popup are separate pages/windows with their own DOM.

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).